# How to edit sudoers files to run a python application to kill processes without giving users the ability to run /bin/kill as root

Tags: python, kill-process, zombie-process

I added a line in /etc/sudoers file:

```
user123 ALL=(ALL:ALL)  NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/killzombies.py
```

The purpose is allow user123 to run /usr/local/bin/killzombies.py to cleanup unwanted/zombie processes without giving the "sodo kill -9" privilege. But I got following error:

Sorry, user123 is not allowed to execute '/bin/kill -9 77752' as root

Comment: Giving anyone root privileges is a very, very bad idea unless they are admins of the system. You  very much need to re-evaluate the owner and group privileges on your server.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Is there a way to allow a user to have root privilege to execute Linux commands in a particular Python script. After exiting the Python script, the user will no longer to have a root privilege.  Thanks!